# Python PIL load() giving pixel map with data as tuple with 4 values

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(name)
pixelMap = im.load()
print(pixelMap[0,0])
```

this outputs `(238, 238, 238, 255)`

I suppose the first 4 values are the RGB values but what is the last 255 value??

Comment: It's most likely an alpha channel - in other words, you're dealing with an image format that supports transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last value (255) is the value in the alpha-channel. If you open your image with GIMP you can see the alpha full white channel.